# Equivalent ODE forward integration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, vector-fields

Consider a Cauchy problem $$\dot x(t)=f(t,x(t)),\quad x(T)=x_T \qquad (*)$$ where $T>0$ and we would like to compute $x(0)$.

I wonder how to construct an ode such that integrating forward the latter would lead to $x(0)$.
I don't have precise idea on how to obtain such equivalent ode: I would use time reparameterization, change of coordinates ...

---

I propose the ode:

$$\dot z(t) = -f(t,z(T-t)),\quad z(0)=x_T, \quad t\in [0,T]
$$
then we can recover $x$ from $x(t)=z(T-t)$.

But in the general case (without symmetry on the solutions), this may be difficult to handle numerically, because in numerical implementation, we must provide $g(t,z(t))=-f(t,z(T-t))$ which is not suitable because we can't express (in general) $z(T-t)$ in terms of $z(t)$.

Are there any other odes that could be integrated forward to obtain $x(0)$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach works, because it yields another ODE:

Let $z(t)=x(T-t)$. Then

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial t}z(t)=\frac{\partial }{\partial t}x(T-t)\\
=-x'(T-t)=-f(T-t,x(T-t))\\
=-f(T-t,z(t)).
$$